# How install pyjags in Google-COLAB

Tags: installation, pip, google-colaboratory

Please help me to install pyjags on google-colaboratory environment. I've tried this command:

```
> %pip install pyjags
Collecting pyjags
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b5/23/22e8468ff9f8e0d5472e388c783c45b3c42b562df4b9b6bab483d935b5bc/pyjags-1.3.7.tar.gz
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

but it gives me this error. How can I solve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install `jags` first.

Run both of these in a cell.

```
!sudo apt-get install jags
!pip install pyjags
```